# Using view models in MvcView scaffolding templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have viewmodel

```
public class ClientIndexViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int SurrogateId { get; set; } // not primary key just used in templating
    public IEnumerable<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

And I have created a new MvcView t4 template called `Index.cs.t4`. When I create a new view from the controller and add my model class as the `ClientIndexViewModel`, the view template ( index.cshtml )  is generated, but without the properties from the `IEnumerable<Client>`

**Templated Index.cshtml**

```
<table class="table">
<!-- Client properties should be here .. i think -->
<tr>
    <th></th> <!-- This is all empty because i dont really know what i am doing -->
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.SurrogateId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.SurrogateId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.SurrogateId })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Which makes sense when i look at the template file.

**Index.cs.t4**

```
<#
IEnumerable<PropertyMetadata> properties = ModelMetadata.Properties;
foreach (PropertyMetadata property in properties) {
if (property.Scaffold && !property.IsPrimaryKey && !property.IsAssociation)     {
#>
<#
    if (property.IsAssociation && GetRelatedModelMetadata(property) == null)     {
        continue;
    }
#>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.<#= GetValueExpression(property)     #>)
    </th>
<#
    }
}
#>
```

I would like to be able to specifically target the `IEnumerable<Client>` property on the viewmodel for the `properties` variable, to be the properties for the enumeration on `PropertyMetaData`

I figured I might be able to create a method in `ModelMEtadataFunctions.include.t4` file. Just not too sure how , or if i even should be doing that

Comment: Are you sure that you added ClientIndexViewModel as model to Templated Index.cshtml?

Comment: @MuratYıldız As the class model in the dialog box? Yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack that makes this work. This is by no means any sort of ideal to use, but considering it is just scaffolding code for visual studio and not project code it doesn't seem too bad

Firstly . The Model Class, for the view, is the entity type that i want to enumerate through. So i get all the properties for the Client from the client entity and not my viewmodel. However the model is wrong ( of course ) . So in the template file, `Index.cs.t4` I change the control blocks based on the `ViewDataTypeShortName` parameter ( found in the `Imports.include.t4` ) . This gives me `Client` , because i am selecting the client entity.

So for instance in a `foreach` it would typically display

```
 @foreach (var item in Model){
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => <#= "item." + GetValueExpression(property) #>) 
    </td>
 </tr>
 }
```

Now i control that by adding

```
@foreach (var item in Model.<#= NewViewDataTypeShortName #>)
// NewViewDataTypeShortName is created with 
// <# string NewViewDataTypeShortName = ViewDataTypeShortName + 's'; #> 
// Based on my naming convention.
```

Which produces this in the `Index.cshtml`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Clients) {
```

Then i add my @model by creating a method in the `ModelMetaDataFunctions.cs.include.t4`

```
string GetViewModelName(string ViewDataTypeName,string   
                       ViewDataTypeShortName,string ViewName){

       string[] names = ViewDataTypeName.Split(new string[]{"."},StringSplitOptions.None);
       return names[0] + ".Domain.ViewModels." + 
       ViewDataTypeShortName + ViewName +"ViewModel";
}
```

Which is called in the `Index.cs.t4` like so

```
@model <#= GetViewModelName(ViewDataTypeName,ViewDataTypeShortName,ViewName) #>
```

And then display in the `Index.cshtml` as

```
@model TaskR.Domain.ViewModels.ClientIndexViewModel
```

This gives me basically everything i need. Its not ideal and relies way to heavily on naming conventions that i am not sure i would like to hand over to another developer. For instance this will not scaffold correctly if the viewmodel is created in the main project, because it is based on a separate project for the data class's. Also the entity type names and view model names have a very strict convention for this to work ..

Please post if you have a better idea, i dont think this is a best practice

Answer (score 0):

If your Models folder is in the same folder root that ViewModels folder you could use

```
string GetViewModelName(string ViewDataTypeName,string   
                   ViewDataTypeShortName,string ViewName){

   string[] names = ViewDataTypeName.Split('.');
   names[names.Length-2] = "ViewModels";
   names[names.Length-1] = names[names.Length-1]+"ViewModel";
   return string.Join(".",names);
}
```

It is little more generic after me